django alter checkconstraint with json field
I want to alter table to add check constraint in mysql, if using sql like below
ALTER TABLE Test
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_sss
CHECK(
  JSON_SCHEMA_VALID(
    '{
       "type":"object",
       "properties":{
         "latitude":{"type":"number", "minimum":-90, "maximum":90},
         "longitude":{"type":"number", "minimum":-180, "maximum":180}
       },
       "required": ["latitude", "longitude"]
    }',
    sss
  )
)

class Test(models.Model):
    sss = models.JSONField(null=True)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check = ???????),
        ]

how to write this sql in model ?

Why use a JSONField if the schema is fixed? Then it makes no sense to use JSON.

@willeM_VanOnsem just an example, I just want to know how to do alter check constraint

Django very likely did not cover this check yet.

Usually if data is structured, it makes not much sense to store that as a JSON blob in a relational database, because it makes querying less expressive and less efficient as well.
So you work with:
class Test(models.Model):
    # sss = models.JSONField(null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(Q(latitude__range=(-90, 90)), name='latitude_range'),
            CheckConstraint(
                Q(longitude__range=(-180, 180)), name='longitude_range'
            ),
        ]
